# media queries to hide the 1st element doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I have several `<hr />` and I use the below css in media queries

```
hr:first-child {
```

no luck, why? My scope of media queries is ok, other class work fine but not this one, I wonder.. ??

Comment: Can you please show the styles that you are applying to this selector, before and inside the media query ?

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
hr:first-of-type
{
display:none;
}
```

As the name of the selector suggests, `:first-child` refers to the first child of the element, and `:first-of-type` refers to the first element of that type. I believe you are looking for the latter.

Answer (score 1):

To select the first `HR` You need to use

```
hr:first-of-type {display: none; }
```

Using the `:first-child` pseudo selector selects every `hr` element that is the first child of it's parent.

Using the `:first-of-type` pseudo selector selects the first `hr` element of it's parent

Comment: seen this before, what is the differences?

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try like the following:

`<hr class="hideinsmallscreen" />`

Change the class name as you want `.hideinsmallscreen`

Within media query you can use the class to hide that `<hr/>`

```
.hideinsmallscreen{
     display:none;
  }
```